# Anchoring a button that is inside a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, anchor

I have a panel anchored to top-left_BOTTOM of the form. there is a button at the bottom of this panel that I want to move correctly when I am resizing the form by pulling down  the bottom edge of the form.  but now the panel is moving correctly but the button does not.  what should I set to do this?  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the anchor of the button? It should say "bottom" but not "top".
The panel is resizing correctly because you attached it to the top and to the bottom of the form. Now you have to attach the button to the parent's (the panel's) bottom only (not top).

Answer (score 1):

Anchor the button to the right and bottom